# Regular Expression to capture values between colons including blank values

Tags: regex, adobe-analytics

I have a string with potentially 9 values delimited by colons. I will have 2 potential structures for that string:

```
value1:value2:value3:value4:value5::value7:value8:
value1:value2:value3:value4::value6:value7::value9
```

I need to be able to break this down and store each individual value. We've come up with something like this

```
^(.+)?\:(.+)?\:(.+)?\:(.+)?\:(.+)?(\:\:)(.+)?\:(.+)?(\:\:)$
```

but it isn't allowing for both structures.

This is being used in Adobe Analytics to capture the individual values if that helps at all.

Comment: Try [`^([^:\n]*):([^:\n]*):([^:\n]*):([^:\n]*):([^:\n]*):([^:\n]*):([^:\n]*):([^:\n]*):([^:\n]*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/CRnys1/1). You may remove `\n` if you are not running it on a multiline content.

Comment: Are fewer than 9 values permitted? That is, is `value1:value2`, for example, a valid string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is for **Classification Rule Builder**(CRB). @Wiktor's commented answer is okay, but you shouldn't need to include the `\n` in the regex he provided. One thing his regex assumes though is that all of your existing keys have have all 9 values or at least placeholder colons for them.  In my experience in practice this isn't always the case; historical data may have less because requirements were changed. If this is the case for you, then here is a slightly modified regex that @Wiktor provided:

`^([^:]*)(?::([^:]*))?(?::([^:]*))?(?::([^:]*))?(?::([^:]*))?(?::([^:]*))?(?::([^:]*))?(?::([^:]*))?(?::([^:]*))?$`

This will give you `$1` through `$9` for the values:

**`value1:value2:value3:value4:value5:value6:value7:value8:value9`**

```
$1 = value1
$2 = value2
$3 = value3
$4 = value4
$5 = value5
$6 = value6
$7 = value7
$8 = value8
$9 = value9
```

Or you can have empty `::` placeholders for them, e.g.

**`value1:value2::value4:value5::value7:value8:value9`**

```
$1 = value1
$2 = value2
$3 = 
$4 = value4
$5 = value5
$6 = 
$7 = value7
$8 = value8
$9 = value9
```

And it will also match the present values if you don't have the full 9 value string, e.g.

**`value1:value2::value4`**

```
$1 = value1
$2 = value2
$3 = 
$4 = value4
```